# Cannot select time field for default index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm using kibana-4. Following the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html) I should be able to create an index by putting this in my elasticsearch.yaml file:

```
PUT .kibana
{
        "index.mapper.dynamic": true
}
```

I'm not sure I understand how to do this, because a yaml file should not take values formatted like the above block, right?

I noticed that `.kibana` was a default index, so after inputting it into the kibana console, I was asked to input a time field for the default index. However, the input HTML element is a dropdown that contained no options. Without selecting a time-field option I am not allowed to create a default index. What am I supposed to do? Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem faced by you. Even i faced the same while using Kibana 4 for first time.

Here are 2 possible solutions to your problem:-

1. Input  data into elasticsearch which contains a timestamped field. So upon inputting data that field will be directly recognized by Kibana & would be showed to you in the dropdown menu (where you are currently seeing empty).

  **It is empty because Kibana couldn't recognize the timestamped field from the data inserted by you in elasticsearch.**

2. Untick the option of  **Index contains time-based events** which will allow you to just enter your index name & access Kibana.

 Note:- while using Option 2 & specifying index name as .kibana you would notice that it doesn't contain any field or data because .kibana doesnt store any data.

I would suggest you to create an index using curl command and insert data in it with or without timestamped field. If inserted data without timestamped field use Option 2 otherwise use Option 1.